# Start and stop MERN app at a particular time

Tags: server, chat, virtual, mern

Does anyone have experience of how to start and stop a MERN app cleanly in a production environment at a particular time, say start at 9 am and stop at 5pm? The application is hosted with a client-server part in a virtual environment.S
TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a cron job. When the cron job is called you can kill the application or restart it.

```
const cron = require('cron')
const nrc = require('node-run-cmd')

cron.schedule('* * 9 * *', () => {
  nrc.run('npm start')
});

cron.schedule('* * 17 * *', () => {
  nrc.run('pkill -f node')
});
```

If you don't want to kill all the node apps, get the pid first and use the appropriate pkill command

Comment: how can I run a cron job in a particular folder to start my app

Comment: @MohdSaoodakhtar I've updated my answer with a sample code.